# chaining build targets in Makefile and maintaining order of execution

Tags: linux, makefile, build, gnu-make

I have a Makefile defined loosely in the following way

```
pre_build:
    cp build/Dockerfile .

post_build:
    echo "complete"
    rm Dockerfile

build_docker:
    echo "do something with the Dockerfile"

build: pre_build build_docker post_build
```

But my build always fails complaining `Dockerfile` can't be found. However, the actual pre_build and actual copy of Dockerfile works. And if I remove the post_build part, after the build is complete I can see the Dockerfile in the dir.
 I was always in the in the impression that in chained Makefile targets, the order is maintained. But this looks like, something weird is happening with the order of implicit parallel builds on targets.

I tried multiple ways to force order, but nothing worked.

upd:
I tried in Mac and Linux, same behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel builds do not have enforced order, almost by definition. Try this:

```
pre_build:
    ...

post_build: build_docker
    ...

build_docker: pre_build
    ...

build: post_build
```

**EDIT:**

If `pre_build` and `post_build` are defined in another makefile which you may not alter, just do this:

```
include Makefile.other

post_build: build_docker

build_docker: pre_build
    ...

build: post_build
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I cannot do this because pre_build and post_build are coming from another Makefile which I don't have control over. It is getting included in the actual make file.